# Can I call receiver function without signal call?

Tags: django, signals, receiver

I have receiver function

```
@receiver(paid)
def add_transaction(sender, payment_uid, **kwargs): 
    do some stuff
```

which is called after payment. Can I call it also explicit, without signal?

Comment: What is your goal with this?

Comment: I make a bonus system which does not require to be paid, but seller has to now to send the item anyway

Answer (score 0):

If anybody ever wonder: the answer is yes, I can :)